# Como enviar variables atraves de ajax con laravel 5?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Hola soy algo nueva en todo esto de laravel y ajax, y a modo de practicar quisiera saber como poder usar ajax en laravel....

[image: este es el input y el boton]

[image: y este es el error que me sale al momento de que presiono el boton confirmar]

en fin,tengo el siguiente codigo:

index.blade.php

```
   <input type="text" name="textvalue" id="texto">
    <button type="button" id="confirm">confirmar</button>

     <script type="text/javascript">

      $('#confirm').click(function(){
          alert("boton funciona");
             var input=$('#texto').val();

            $.ajax({
            url: 'archivos/create2.blade.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: {'texto': input},
            success:function(data){
                alert('los datos fueron registrados correctamente');
                }, error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log('error::'+errorThrown);
                     console.log('error::'+textStatus);
                      console.log('error::'+jqXHR);
                   }

            });                  
        });
   </script>
```

Routes.php

```
   Route::resource('/archivos', 'ArchivoController');
   Route::post('archivos/create2', 'ArchivoController@show');
```

ArchivoController.php

```
class ArchivoController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
  {
    //$title = "Modulo de Archivos";
   //EN ESTE sector esto que dice archivos. es de mi carpeta en donde esta el index
    return view('archivos.index', compact('archivos', 'title'));
  }

public function show(){
$data=$this->input->post();
return view('archivos.create2');
  }
    public function store(Request $request)
  {       
  }

}
```

create2.blade.php

```
  @extends('templade')
  @section('content')
   <?php
     $entra=$_POST['texto'];
      echo "tabla texto : $entra ";

   ?>
  @endsection
```

Comment: La `url` de `ajax` debe apuntar a la acción del controlador que esta apuntada también por una `url` en su caso sería `url: 'archivos/create2'`, no a una vista. Si desea enviar variables de una vista a otra, no es necesario `ajax`.

Comment: bueno vale, gracias, pero en si estoy practicando para poder enviar variables despues de jquery pero queria entender un poco mas esto de ajax.

Answer (score 1):

**Para conocimiento general voy a explicar detalladamente como registra un dato en Laravel usando Ajax Paso por Paso.**

La tabla que estoy usando como prueba es la siguiente:

**PRIMERO:**
Crear y Ejecutar esta migracion para que tengan la tabla:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CrearTablaCursos extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cursos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('titulo');
            $table->text('descripcion');
            $table->boolean('destacado')->default(true);
            $table->text('detalle')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cursos');
    }
}
```

**SEGUNDO:**
Crear las rutas en el archivo web.php (la primera es para llamar al controlador y la segunda se usa para almacenar los datos del formulario)

```
// EJEMPLO AJAX Creacion de registro
Route::get('AjaxCrear', 'AjaxCrearController@create');
Route::post('AjaxCrear', 'AjaxCrearController@store');
```

**TERCERO:**
Crear un controlador para procesar los datos y manejar las rutas:

```
php artisan make:controller AjaxCrearController
```

**CUARTO:**

Abrir el controlador y colocar el siguiente codigo con siguientes:

```
<?php

namespace cursos\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Cursos;

class AjaxCrearController extends Controller
{
    // Mostrar Formulario CURSO
    public function create()
    {
        return view('AjaxCrear');
    }

// registrar Nuevo CURSO
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // se agrega el ajax
    if ($request->ajax()) {

          // Guardar Objeto
          $curso = new Cursos(); // Crea objeto
          $curso->titulo = $request->input('titulo');
          $curso->descripcion = is_null($request->input('descripcion'))? '' : $request->input('descripcion');
              // capturar destacado y convertirlo en valor 1 y 0
              if($request->input('destacado')!=null){
                  $destacado=1;
              }else{
                  $destacado=0;
              }
          $curso->destacado = $destacado;
          $curso->detalle = $request->input('detalle');
          $curso->save(); // guarda el registro

        // retorno de datos via json
        return response()->json(
            $curso->toArray()
        );

    }
    // fin ajax
}



}
```

Explicacion:

1) El metodo create() 
Se encarga de mostrar la vista del formulario

2) Metodo store()
 recibe los datos del formulario a traves del $request,  se pregunta si son pasados por el metodo ajax por medio del if ($request->ajax()) de ser verdad se ejecuta el contenido del codigo el cual crea una nueva instancia de la clase modelo Cursos la cual permitira crear un nuevo registro. se pasan los datos recibidos de los campos input a los atributos titulo, descripcion, destacado y detalle. se salva usando el metodo save() Finalmente se envia una respuesta al formulario mediante json con response()->json().

**QUINTO:**
crear el modelo:

```
php artisan make:model Cursos
```

**SEXTO** 
editar el modelo Cursos.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cursos extends Model
{
    // indice al modelo cual tabla se va manejar
    protected $table = 'cursos';


}
```

**SEPTIMO:**
Crear la vista: **AjaxCrear.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title></title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS  -->
  <link href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
     #notificacion {
        display: none; position: absolute; top:50%; width: 80%; left: 0; right: 0;
        margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">CREAR CURSOS</h1>
<!-- se copia el bloque form de register -->
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('AjaxCrear') }}" id="formulario">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="titulo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-left">Titulo</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="titulo" type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" value="" required autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>     
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Breve Descripcion</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="descripcion"></textarea>
        </div>     
        <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="defaultCheck1" name="destacado">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                 Mostrar en Galeria Carrusel
                </label>
        </div>       
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Descripcion Larga</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="detalle"></textarea>
        </div>
       <!-- boton de registrar -->
        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
            <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="BtnRegistrar">
                    Registrar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- notificacion de grabado -->
<div id="notificacion" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"  role="alert" 
style="">
   <strong>Se ha Agregado un Registro</strong>
</div>

{{--  Historico de Cursos registrados --}}
<div id='historico' style="display: none;">
    <h3>Historico de Creaciones</h3>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="{{ asset('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        // boton de registrar
        $('#BtnRegistrar').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var dataString = $('#formulario').serialize(); // carga todos los campos para enviarlos
            // AJAX
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ url('AjaxCrear') }}",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                        $('#historico').fadeIn(); // mostrar historico
                        $('#notificacion').fadeIn(); // mostrar notificacion
                        setTimeout(function(){ $('#notificacion').fadeOut(); }, 1000); // ocultar mensaje 1s
                        $('#formulario')[0].reset(); // limpiar form
                        // leer el JSON de retono
                        $(data).each(function(key,value) {
                            $("ul").append("<li>  "+ value.titulo + " fecha: "+ value.created_at + " ID:" + value.id + " </li>");
                        })

                }
            });

        });


    }); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Explicacion:**

```
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Se llama a la libreria JQuery para implementar el AJAX.

```
    $('#BtnRegistrar').click(function(event) {
```

Este es el boton para registrar / Submit

```
        event.preventDefault();
```

Se previene la accion por defecto del boton submit

```
var dataString = $('#formulario').serialize(); // carga todos
```

Serializamos los datos de los campos del formulario para obtener los datos

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ url('AjaxCrear') }}",
            data: dataString,
```

Ejecutamos el codigo AJAX con el tipo POST por ser mas seguro y enviar volumen de datos, colocamos el url, y en data se coloca la informacion recaudada por la serializacion.

```
            success: function(data) {
```

Esta es la respuesta del AJAX al ejecutar exitosamente el proceso y recibimos los datos de la variable data.

```
                    $('#historico').fadeIn(); // mostrar historico
                    $('#notificacion').fadeIn(); // mostrar
```

Mostrarmos el historio y notificacion.

```
                    setTimeout(function(){ $('#notificacion').fadeOut(); }, 1000); // ocultar mensaje 1s
```

Ocultamos la notificacion.

```
$('#formulario')[0].reset(); // limpiar form
```

Limpiamos el formulario para agregar otros registros.

```
                    $(data).each(function(key,value) {
                        $("ul").append("<li>  "+ value.titulo + " fecha: "+ value.created_at + " ID:" + value.id + " </li>");
```

hacemos un recorrido a la variable data para leer el contenido del JSON recibido el cual agregamos un nuevo item `<li>` al `<ul>` el cual tendra el titulo, fecha y id del nuevo registro.

**OCTAVO:**

Probar la carga de datos leyendo la tabla **cursos** a traves de PhPMyAdmin

**Nota**: El ejemplo es sencillo para entender el funcionamiento del AJAX en Laravel y poder implementarlo en sus futuros proyectos.